# Finding and clicking on elements in a new page by Selenium

Tags: selenium

The situation is as such -

- From "something/login.php" page, i am clicking on a button which takes me to the home page "something/dashboard.php"
- Trying to click on a element on the new page "something/dashboard.php" but unable to locate element.
- I have then checked the currenturl with

`String actualUrl = driver.getCurrentUrl();`

and i am getting "something/login.php" page which means the driver is in the previous page. How do i change my focus to the new page and find elements of it?

Here is my code -

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    //Set chromedriver path
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\Tools\\New folder\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");


    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();


    String url =  "something";
    driver.get(url);

driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("something");
    driver.findElement(By.id("password-field")).sendKeys("something");
    driver.findElement(By.id("btn3")).click();

for (String handle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {

        driver.switchTo().window(handle);}

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"accordion\"]/li[3]/a")).click();
```

Comment: Your code trials please.

Comment: edited the question with code.

Comment: After login please use driver.navigate().refresh(); and let me know

Comment: @MahmudRiad, It worked. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Confusedkangaroo i have added the answer. If it is working then please accept it by selecting the tick icon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use below code after login

```
driver.navigate().refresh();
```